# How to reverse explode dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exploded

I have been struggling to reverse explode a dataframe that I have initially exploded. I needed to split and exploded it at first so that I can check each value in this dataframe (df1) exist in the othere dataframe (df2). There are columns that contains semicolon separated strings so I needed to split them so I can check their availability on df2 one-by-one. I have seen similar questions that I tried their solutions but the dataframe on these questions do not have empty cells (empty strings).

Example original df1 (Before exploded):

[image]

After exploded:

[image]

```
from itertools import product, chain
import pandas as pd

explode_rows = chain.from_iterable(product([Col1], [Col2], Col3.split(;), Col4.split(;), Col5.split(;)) 
            for Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 in df1.to_numpy())
df1 = pd.DataFrame(explode_rows, columns = df1.columns)
```

Now I need to reverse explode this split column values so that I can easily filter df2 with a list ['a','b','c'] at once where never needed.

This what i get when trying to reverse the explode. col3,4,5 will have empty cells something as like in this example. but I always have stuff like [], [''], '','' in this empty cells which i do not want as when I try to filter df2, this things are used and cannot filter with them. So i need to reverse explode and leave empty cell empty as they were. Please not that this empty cells actually have empty strings not Nan.

This is some of the things I tried, but almost give me the same output as below.

```
df1 = df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'], as_index=False).agg(list)


df1 = (df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])
        .agg(Col3=('Col3', ','.join(),
             Col4=('Col4', ','.join),
             Col5=('Col5', ','.join),)
        .reset_index())
    

df1 = df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'], as_index=False).agg(list)


df1 = (df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])
        .agg(Col3=('Col3', ','.join(),
             Col4=('Col4', ','.join),
             Col5=('Col5', ','.join),)
        .reset_index())
        

df1 = (df1.groupby([['Col1','Col2'])
      .agg({'Col3': lambda x: x.tolist(),
            'Col4': lambda x: x.tolist(),
            'Col3': lambda x: x.tolist(),})
      .reset_index())
```

I have tried to replace the empty strings with Nan then reverse explode and try to replace them back to empty strings with no luck.

[image]
Any help will be appreciated, as well as the good practices that I can you for efficiency and clean pythonic way.

Comment: Your expected output for Col3, Col4, and Col5 is a list of integers, or None? The first row of Col3 should be [1,2,3] and the last row of Col3 should be None?

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for the help.
For the sake of this question, please you can interpret the numbers as strings.
So Col3 will be ['1','2','3'] and the last row I want it to be and empty string, not Nan or None.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to continue with:

```
df1['Col3'] == df1['Col3'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
df1['Col4'] == df1['Col4'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
df1['Col5'] == df1['Col5'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
```

Comment: Hi @Cristina,
Thank you for the help.
I Have just tried your suggestion and it gives me the unwanted '[]' as explained in my question. As shown below Col5 have [, ,] that I do not want and need.
  Col1  Col2       Col3       Col4    Col5
0  aaa  eee    [1, 2, 3]   [1, 1, 1]     [, , ]
1  bbb   fff            [1]             []      [3]
2  ccc  ggg        [1, 2]       [2, 2]      [, ]
3  ddd  hhh             []             []       []

Answer (score 0):

I've created a general purpose solution for this in which it will work on any other dataframe.

I would say you only need the implode part of it.

```py
def explosive_df(df, column: str):
    def implode(data_frame=()):
        inner_df = data_frame if len(data_frame) > 0 else df

        def reduce_columns():
            acc = {}
            for col in inner_df.columns:
                if col == column:
                    acc[col] = lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()
                    continue
                acc[col] = lambda x: x.iloc[0]

            return acc

        return inner_df.groupby(inner_df.index, as_index=False).agg(
            reduce_columns()
        ).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df.explode(column), implode
```

Usage:

```py
exploded, implode = explosive_df(data_frame, 'column_name')

imploded = implode(exploded)
```

the imploded part is supposed to look exactly the same as the data_frame if no edits happened before imploding.

Try it out:

```py
print(imploded.sort_index() == data_frame.sort_index())
```

And it is supposed to explode and implode any dataframe I could think of.